# How to make the ajax 'data' that come with 2 values to get each value separately?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

```
<?
 function phpfunction(){

 //insert data to database //some codes work inside this.

$return_arr[] = array($arrResult,         // include only one value
                      $response_array['status'] );//success or not success value

return $return_arr;
}
?>
```

This $return_arr[] value return to the javascript ajax file >>

```
                    $.ajax({
                            url: 'PHPMethodCalls_AL.php',
                            type: 'post',
                            data: {... post many values to php function..   },
                            success: function(data) {
                            alert(data);
```

//data is successfully come as this format >> [[["Testing123"],"success"]]

```
                            var results = JSON.parse(data);
                            alert(results);
```

// this alert got >> Testing123,success

```
                        },
```

//this one is post value to function

```
$newCIarrayList = array();
$newCIarrayList = phpfunction(..data include );
echo json_encode($newCIarrayList);
```

What should I do to get each value as "Testing123" and "success" value separately? I tried with split(",") function but it didn't work.

Comment: Not shown: Where you emit JSON in the PHP world.

Comment: @tadman I edited the codes.

Answer (score 1):

You can seperate in php function before response to ajax like below .Then you can get easy

```
<?
 function phpfunction(){

    //insert data to database //some codes work inside this.

    $return_arr = array("data"   =>$arrResult,         // include only one value
                        "status" =>$response_array['status'] );//success or not success value    
    return $return_arr;
}
?>
```

> var results = JSON.parse(data);
>
> alert(results.data || results.status);

Comment: when I alert the results value, it comes with [Object,Object] , no value come to the data.

Comment: debug with `console.log()` will help you to get object value

Comment: Thanks. the results value come but results.data value is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

What you get back in `success: function(data)` is a stringified json of a nested array: `[[["Testing123"],"success"]]`.

To get your status and payload out of this structure, you can use the following snippet.

```js
var data = '[[["Testing123"],"success"]]';
var parsedData = JSON.parse(data);
console.log(parsedData); // quite nested

var status = parsedData[0][1];
console.log(status);

var payload = parsedData[0][0][0];
console.log(payload);
```

Or using ES6 destructuring:

```js
var data = '[[["Testing123"],"success"]]';
var parsedData = JSON.parse(data);
[[[payload], status]] = parsedData;
console.log(status);
console.log(payload);
```

I would however suggest that you revise your php-side code, and make it so that it forms a simpler structure, ideally:

```
{"status": "success", "payload": "Testing123"}
```